# Sqlite connection string in perl

Tags: perl, sqlite

I am using below sqlite connection string in perl to connect sqlite database and getting following below error

> Can't set DBI::db=HASH(0x2c34194)->{PRAGMA journal_mode}: unrecognised attribute name or invalid value

```
my $driver   = "SQLite"; 
my $database = "C:\\Sample\\Sample_Sqlite\\Activities.db3;PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL;";

my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:dbname=$database";
print $dsn;
my $dbh = DBI->connect(          
    $dsn,                          
    { RaiseError => 1 },         
) or die $DBI::errstr;
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading [the section on PRAGMA in the DBD::SQLite documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::SQLite#Pragma), it looks like you're setting the PRAGMA at the wrong time. It shouldn't be part of the connection string, but an SQL command that is run once you have connected.

```
my $driver   = "SQLite"; 
my $database = "C:\\Sample\\Sample_Sqlite\\Activities.db3";

my $dsn = "DBI:$driver:dbname=$database";
print $dsn;
my $dbh = DBI->connect(          
    $dsn,                          
    { RaiseError => 1 },         
) or die $DBI::errstr;

$dbh->do('PRAGMA journal_mode=WAL');
```

**Update:** It's probably also worth noting that the `journal_mode` setting is persistent. So you only need to set it once, and then you can drop it completely from your connection code.

Comment: Totally I have 64 rows in my database, with this statement I can able to retrieve only two rows.

Comment: @TulasiKumarGM: I don't see how the journal mode would affect the number of rows a query returns. What makes you think you have 64 rows in your table?

Comment: @TulasiKumarGM: But, anyway, your question was about connecting to the database. I think I've fixed that problem for you. If you have further problems, you should ask separate questions about them.

Comment: The only persistent journal mode is `wal`, btw. The others still need to be set for every connection.

Comment: I copied db3 file in one of my local folder and tried to open using Sqlite Studio, so here I can able to see only two rows.
if I copy a .db3 and .db3-wal in one of my local folder and tried to open using Sqlite Studio, so here I can able to see all 64 rows.
so here while connecting .db3, I need to consider .db3-wal also